# How to avoid 504 Gateway Timeout with Laravel mass insert?

Tags: php, mysql

Connections can have 1,000 - 10,000 items passed to it. I keep getting a 504 when trying to hit this controller, I've changed it from individual `Create` to mass `Insert` (one query) but it still throws a 504 if connections are higher than 1000.

How can I improve this code to not throw a 504? I don't really want to expend that time from 60 seconds.

The function that takes the longest is `storeConnections`

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Cache;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreCacheItemRequest;
use App\Models\CacheConnection;
use App\Models\CacheItem;
use App\Models\CacheMedia;
use App\Models\QueueItem;
use App\Models\QueueItemFailed;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StoreController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(StoreCacheItemRequest $request)
    {
        if (CacheItem::where('item', $request->get('item'))->exists())
        {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'Cache item ' . $request->get('item') . ' already exists.'
            ], 500);
        }

        $cache = CacheItem::create([
            'item' => $request->get('item'),
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'picture' => $request->get('picture'),
            'description' => $request->get('description'),
            'connection_count' => $request->get('connection_count'),
            'is_private' => $request->get('is_private'),
            'has_snap' => $request->get('has_snap', false),
            'additional_data' => $request->get('additional_data'),
            'type_id' => $request->get('type_id'),
        ]);

        if ($request->has('connections')) {
            $this->storeConnections($request->get('connections'), $cache->id);
        }

        if ($request->has('pictures')) {
            $this->storeMedia($request->get('pictures'), $cache->id);
        }
    }

    private function storeConnections($connections, $cacheId)
    {
        $connectionData = [];
        foreach ($connections as $item) {
            $queryData[] = [
                'cache_id' => $cacheId,
                'item' => $item
            ];
        }

        CacheConnection::insert($connectionData);

        $queueData = [];

        foreach ($queryData as $item) {
            if (!QueueItem::where('item', $item)->exists() &&
                !QueueItemFailed::where('item', $item)->exists() &&
                !CacheItem::where('item', $item)->exists())
            {
                $queueData[] = [
                    'item' => $item,
                ];
            }
        }

        Queue::insert($queueData);
    }

    private function storeMedia($media, $cacheId)
    {
        foreach ($media as $item) {
            CacheMedia::create([
                'cache_id' => $cacheId,
                'item' => $item
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you solved? I am in a similar situation